# Retain Dropdown List values through a POST ASP.NET Core MVC C#

Tags: post, asp.net-core-mvc

Hi this is probably simple but I'm missing something.

I have a simple cshtml view that binds to a model. That model has a few string values and a few List<>s of lookup values to populate dropdowns with. These lists are initially populated from the database.

On form submit I am posting and validating the string data with Data Annotations like one normally would. No problems there. the ModelState.IsValid catches anything that isn't right.

UPDATE: Code below

```
    [Route("[controller]/{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> BankDetails(Guid id)
    {
        try
        {
            ViewData["User"] = HttpContext.User;
            
            var fedBanks = await _bankLookupService.GetFedBanksAsync();
            BankDetailViewModel vm = new BankDetailViewModel
            {
                BankDetails = await _bankService.GetBankAsync(id),
                C21FedBanks = fedBanks.Select(b => new C21FederalReserveBank { C21FederalReserveBankID = b.Id, Name = b.ValueName }),
                ACHFedBanks = fedBanks,
                States = await _bankLookupService.GetStatesAsync(),
                ClearingEntities = await _bankLookupService.GetClearingEntitiesAsync(),
                Statuses = await _bankLookupService.GetStatusesAsync()
            };

            ViewBag.FedBanks = fedBanks;
            return View("BankDetails", vm);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            await _exceptionLogService.LogError(ex, User.Identity.Name);
            return BadRequest("An error occurred loading the bank details page.");
        }
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateBank(BankDetailViewModel model)
    {
        try
        {
            ViewData["User"] = HttpContext.User;
            
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var fedBanks = await _bankLookupService.GetFedBanksAsync();
                model.C21FedBanks = fedBanks.Select(b => new C21FederalReserveBank { C21FederalReserveBankID = b.Id, Name = b.ValueName });
                model.ACHFedBanks = fedBanks;
                model.States = await _bankLookupService.GetStatesAsync();
                model.Statuses = await _bankLookupService.GetStatusesAsync();
                model.ClearingEntities = await _bankLookupService.GetClearingEntitiesAsync();
                return View("BankDetails", model);
            }

            return RedirectToAction("BankDetails", "BankManagement", new { id = 0, saved = true });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            await _exceptionLogService.LogError(ex, User.Identity.Name);
            return BadRequest("An error occurred updating the bank.");
        }
    }
```

The issue is the model Lists are no longer populated and I would like to avoid looking up those lists again, if I have to return the user to correct their entries. Is there a mechanism to retain those values in the model that gets POSTed, or alternatively can I store those lists somewhere so as not to hit the database continuously while the user gets their entries correct?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Cef, please share enough code to reproduce your issue.

Comment: Code added let me know if you need more info.

Comment: Hi @Cef, from your code sample, it seems you render BankDetails.cshtml.When you post the form data, If the modelstate is valid, it will run the code `RedirectToAction`. If it is not valid, it will run `return View("BankDetails", model);`. And what you want is return view with model and also modelstate error right? But actually if you return view with model, it will maintain the modelstate error by default. So maybe you need share your cshtml? Did you use the default form submit? If you use ajax, it will not render the modelstate when call back by default.

Comment: It returns the modelstate error correctly. That's not the issue. The issue is as the code is now, I have to requery the data for the select lists and I'd rather not hit the database again. Is there a way to save those values for the round trip? Yes it is the default form submit. Ajax would be fine because then I wouldn't be reloading the view.

Comment: If you want to maintain the selected value without requery the data from database, I think ajax maybe a correct way to achieve your requirement. Or did you consider store the query data to session?